# Populating a set of child objects in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, parent-child

I am trying to populate a set of child objects in my parent objects.

`

```
//parent class
@Table(name = "Retail")
public class Retail implements Serializable{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "retail", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Address> address


//child class
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cId", referencedColumnName = "cId")
private Retail retail;

//service class
List<Criterion> criterionList = CriterionBuilder.buildRetailCritList(csr);
List<Retail> retailList = (List<Retail>)retailDao.getByCriteria(criterionList);
```

`

At first, this seems to work.  I can access the set of child objects in each parent object.  On closer inspection, however, there are more parent objects returned than I expected (in "retailList").  It looks like this happens because hibernate is doing a left outer join on the parent and child tables.  This was not my goal.  All I'm trying to do is return the original parent objects, but also have a set of child objects inside each of them.

Any hints or tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.